# Analysis of what probability is required to be found out in a total probability question

Tags: probability, probability-theory

> In a certain town, the probability that it will rain in the afternoon is known to be $0.6$. Moreover, meteorological data indicates that if the temperature at noon is less than or equal to $25°C$, the probability that it will rain in the afternoon is $0.4$. The temperature at noon is equally likely to be above $25°C$, or at/below $25°C$. *What is the probability that it will rain in the afternoon on a day when the temperature at noon is above $25°C$?*
> $\tag{$\text{GATE-CS-2006}$}$

---

After reading the question, I approached as follows:

$$Pr\{\text{rain_afternoon}\} = 0.6 \quad\text{(given)}$$
$$Pr\{\text{rain_afternoon|t$\leqslant 25$}\} = 0.4 \quad\text{(given)}$$
$$Pr\{\text{t$\leqslant 25$}\} = Pr\{\text{t$\gt 25$}\} = 0.5\quad\text{(given)}$$

So using total probability we have:

$$Pr\{\text{rain_afternoon}\}$$
$$=Pr\{\text{rain_afternoon $\land$ t$\leqslant 25$}\}+\require{color}\colorbox{pink}{$Pr\{\text{rain_afternoon $\land$ t$\gt 25$}\}$}$$
$$ =Pr\{\text{t$\leqslant 25$}\}\times Pr\{\text{rain_afternoon|t$\leqslant 25$}\}+Pr\{\text{t$\gt 25$}\}\times \require{color}\colorbox{cyan}{$Pr\{\text{rain_afternoon|t$\gt 25$}\}$}$$

The rest is just value substitution. But problem is that I thought that the probability which is asked the one highlighted with pink in the above calculation. And I got the answer as $0.4$.

But my peers approached in the same manner but they reported the probability highlighted in cyan in the above calculation. After seeing their solution I re-read the the part of the question in italics and came to the conclusion that my peers have assumed the "when" in "given" sense. [But when I read the question for the first time, I felt that they were asking it in the "and" sense. But in proposition and logic, "when" is used in the "if" or "given" sense. ($q$ when $p$). Is it something like that?]

Now I just want to know the interpretation which I had in the beginning, is it at all possible?

Or what I had assumed is only possible if the last sentence in the question is like: *What is the probability that it will rain in the afternoon today and today the afternoon temperature is above $25°C$?* Or what possible statements would mean that I need to calculate the probability in pink and how it is different from the statement when the probability in cyan is required ?

Comment: In the line with the probability in pink, one of those conditions should be  $t > 25$.

Comment: I read the problem as asking for the cyan value.  In the end, this is a question more about the English language... but I can not think off the top of my head where I would have used "when" in place of "and" rather than "given."  As for a question where the answer is the probability in pink (after typo correction), I would phrase as "*What is the probability that tomorrow it will be raining in the afternoon and have the temperature be above $25^\circ$ C*"

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Corrected the typo :)

Comment: @JMoravitz ok, got the intuition.. thanks for the help

Comment: @bittahProfessional Please clarify a point ` If I wanted to ask for the cyan value` in this line did you mean `cyan` ? or it is a typo and it should have been :  `If I wanted to ask for the pink value`

Comment: Thank you Abhishek, I meant pink.  'I second JMoravitz. This question is phrased the way a colloquial speaker would put it. If I wanted to ask for the pink value, I personally would ask "*What is the chance that tomorrow will both have a temperature of above 25°C at noon* and *it will rain in the afternoon?*'

Comment: Thirding my agreement with JMoravitz's comment.